# Cannot fix TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Tags: python, concatenation, typeerror

```
url21 =  "https://www.ft.com/search?sort=date&q=eurozone"
with open(savePath + "Euro_FT" + date + ".txt","wt",-1,'utf-8') as f1:
        ht2 = req.urlopen(url21)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(ht2,'html.parser')
        contents = soup2.select('div.o-teaser__heading > a')[0:]
        for i, contents in enumerate(contents,1):
            f1.write(str(i) + " " + contents.string + "\n")
```

I have used python code aforementioned above for more than 6 months, however, 
suddenly I got error messages `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str`

I tried to find some answers through stackoverflow Q&A, but the cases and answers are a little bit different to my case I think.

I used `for`, not `if`, and following codes works well....

```
url21 =  "https://www.ft.com/world/europe"
with open(savePath + "europe_FT" + date + ".txt","wt",-1,'utf-8') as f1:
        ht2 = req.urlopen(url21)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(ht2,'html.parser')
        contents = soup2.select('div.o-teaser__heading > a')[0:]
        for i, contents in enumerate(contents,1):
            f1.write(str(i) + " " + contents.string + "\n")
```

I've tried and searched for more than an hour.. but I couldn't find the answer...

Comment: `contents.string` is likely `None`?

Comment: `for i, contents in enumerate(contents,1):` It's not good to use same naming of variables inside one block.